Parametric and non parametric probability distributions
Non-parametric Statistical Models on Finite and Infinite Measure Spaces
Consider the following sets of probability densities:

In Amari it says Consider a family $S$ of probability distributions on $X$. Suppose each element of $S$ , a probability distribution, may be parameterized using $n$-real values variables $[\xi^1,...,\xi^n]$ so that $$S=\{p(x;\xi): \xi=[\xi^1,...,\xi^n]\in E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\}$$

For a probability density $p\in X$. let $supp(p)=\{x:p(x)>0\}$,Letting X is redefined as supp(p), this is equivalent to assuming that $p(x;\xi)>0$ holds for all $\xi \in E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$and for all $x \in X$. $P = \{p: X \to \mathbb{R}; p(x) > 0 \text{ and } \int_X p \,d\mu = 1\}$

In enter link description here it says let $(\Omega,B,\mu)$ be a probability space and let us denoted $$M_\mu=\{f\in L^1(\mu):f>0, \mu-a.e , \int fd\mu=1\}$$


Question: I am confused that what is the difference between these three, I mean is the second points means it contains all the pdfs parametric or non parametric? What about the third one then? Also The confusion in point 2 is that does $p$ there means $p(x;\xi)$ since they have just written $p(x)$ so I am confused whether we are taking the parameters or not in this one?
